# Entity Framework 6 .add() with variable table and column name

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, entity-framework-6

I am able to get a somewhat dynamic Entity Framework search result with the following simplified example, which pulls a single result from the DB or Cache:

```
    string strTableName = "TableName2"
    string strColumnName = "MyColumnName"
    int intPrimaryKey = 1

    Type returnType;
    returnType = typeof(TableName1);
    string queryResults = null;
    switch (strTableName)
    {
        case "TableName2":
            returnType = typeof(TableName2);
            break;
    }

    var refColumnName = returnType.GetProperty(strColumnName );
    var query = mydbEntity.Set(returnType).Find(intPrimaryKey );
    var queryResults = refColumnName.GetValue(query).ToString();
```

This can also be adapted for Updating a record:

```
        DataQuery.LeadsEntity.Entry(query).Property(strColumnName ).CurrentValue = "Whatever";
        DataQuery.LeadsEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Is there an equivalent for way for .set(returnType).Add()? I'm not sure if there is a way to do this type of thinking using variable table and column names:

```
DataQuery.LeadsEntity.Set(returnType).Add(new returnType { PrimayKeyName = 1, refColumnName = "Something" });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know a priori what's the name of the primary key property, it could be a little painful to get it from the type.

[This](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/EntityKeyHelper.cs#L53) is the way I found more reliable to retrieve the primary key from the entity type:

```
private string[] GetKeyNames(DbContext context, Type entityType)
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    //create method CreateObjectSet with the generic parameter of the base-type
    MethodInfo method = typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", Type.EmptyTypes)
                                             .MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
    dynamic objectSet = method.Invoke(objectContext, null);
    IEnumerable<dynamic> keyMembers = objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers;
    string[] keyNames = keyMembers.Select(k => (string)k.Name).ToArray();
    _keyNamesCache[entityType] = keyNames;
    return keyNames;
}
```

But assuming your primary keys are always a single property, you could use reflection to create the entity object and set its properties like this:

```
private void CreateEntity(Type entityType, object pkValue, Dictionary<string, object> Columns)
{
    // Create the new entity
    var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);
    // Get the primary key property name
    var pkName = GetKeyNames(context, entityType).First(); 
    // Set Pk value
    entityType.GetProperty(pkName).SetValue(entity, pkValue);
    // Set other column(s)
    foreach (var col in Columns)
    {
        entityType.GetProperty(col.Key).SetValue(entity, col.Value);
    }
    // Add the entity to the DbSet
    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        context.Set(entityType).Add(entity);
    }
}
```